# to Protect a Control in Form

Tags: c#, controls

I want to keep removing my control in form. The problem is a bit complicated then I hope I can explain it as well.

I will give my project which is my thesis to tutor and I want to put a sign on my project. I created a private control which is a label and I put this control to my main form.
And I created a dll and it controls "my private control" is there or not.

I don't want it to be changed by someone because on label, I wrote my name and some information. I want to keep this information from my control. The tutor must not change it. It must me my signature. But I am not sure how can I do it as well.

I want to define that project is mine and they can't change this signature. how can I do it simply and strongly way?

They must not change coordinator or visiblity or text. I want to protect all of property of my control.

Comment: Do you really not trust your tutor? You can't protect something like that when you hand over the source code. They can change whatever they wish.

Comment: I dont trust him ) becae I know that he will give my project to another student to develop it more.. But the project is completly mine and I worked over it so much.Then I dont want they to access everything ..Then I used some dll files and they cant change it, well I can use dll for protect,but how I use my control in dll file? because I cant use form control in dll file as you know

Comment: If you are handing over code, why not publish it open source (codeplex/bitbucket or similar).  Then it will be clearly and publicly credited as your work.  If someone wants to develop it further, no problem, they can't then claim the work as their own.

Comment: its my thesis and I have to give my project. I am not aganist opensource but I know that they will sell my project, its not good... but I have to give my project to tutor.. otherwise I will fail..

Comment: Perhaps you should get a tutor that you trust? Put your education in good hands and all that jazz. I say this a lot on here, but this is a human resources problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: i wanted to just protect my project in programming way.. anyway i will handle it.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not technicaly possible . If you give them a source code they can do whatever they want with it. In SE business there is code copyright and legal issues bind with that concept. Where code author has a *possibility* to protect intellectual property (by the way it's a difficult legal issue cause the code is a just characters sequence).

In academic world, if it's not about research thesis, don't think you can do anything.

By the way all this stuff is country dependent.

Comment: Thanx but I wrote some dll files and I dont give source code of dlls.. just main project.. Then I can protect my project with dll file.. And I will tell tutor its not my dll,its prepared before by someone and I used those dlls.. and he cant do anything because he will not know this dll files are mine..